# How to expand Power BI pop-up windows? I can't see the buttons

Tags: powerbi-desktop

Every time Power BI has a pop-up window, I am unable to see the necessary buttons to continue.

This happens for any window that pop ups.

[image: See picture for Quick Measure Window]

Currently I just find a way around it using DAX, or ctrl + alt + delete to end the window. But I need to resolve this.

I read this was a known issue resolved with an update, but that never happened. It's hard to find anyone else experiencing this problem.

I've tried using my work laptop without a monitor connected, while connected, and all different screen resolutions but the problem remains. Using Power BI Desktop.

Has anyone else experienced this?